# Is there a way to load json file using Backbone.js?

Tags: json, backbone.js

I want to load json file using Backbone JS and then perform sorting and searching functions on the data. Can this be done using only Backbone. I have just started learning Backbone so I am kind of lost.

Comment: Create a `Backbone.Collection`, point its URL at your JSON file, and search away.

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be done using only backbone. Here's a basic example of what [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) suggested:

```js
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two',
    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
        this.listenTo(this, 'sync', this.sort);
    },
    sort: function() {
        this.each(function(data) {
            document.write(data.get('key')); // should write "value"
        });
    }
});

var collection = new Collection();
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js'></script>
```

Using Backbone for sorting and searching data is particularly nice, since you have access to Underscore's methods. See the [Backbone Collection docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) and the [available Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) for more info.

Comment: Yes got it. So I can use underscore methods such as sortBy and find to implement searching and sorting functions right?

Comment: @user0428 Yup! You'll just need to access the data you're sorting and searching via Backbone's `get` function when you use the available Underscore methods.